# How do I initialize a smart pointer which is a class member?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Fairly new to C++ and so this is probably a really silly question. I need the `cube_normals` pointer to be accessed by both member functions `read_models()` and `proc_models()`, and the pointer must be initialized each time I call `read_models()`.

Inside the member function I could do :

```
PointCloud<A>::Ptr cube_normals (new PointCloud<A>);
```

I could pass the pointers to the other function but there are 12 such pointers I am using and its probably not the cleanest way to solve this problem.

This is the code snippet. Thanks in advance!

```
class preproc
{

public:

    preproc();
    ~preproc();
    PointCloud<A>::Ptr cube_normals;

    void read_models();
    void proc_models();

private:

    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::NodeHandle nh_priv;
};
```

Comment: Since `read_models()` and `proc_models()` are methods in the same class, nothing special needs to happen for them to access `cube_normals`, a member of the same class. They just access it as if it was a local variable. Your question is unclear. If you do not have a full understanding of C++ fundamentals, the best answer would be to continue reading your C++ book, and understanding the material presented.

Comment: Are your other smart pointers all of class `PointCloud<A>::Ptr` or are there different types used rather than `A`?

Comment: If you are asking how to reset `cube_normals` so it points to a new object, then it's `cube_normals.reset(new PointCloud<A>)`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, apologies if the question is unclear. I need to re-initialize the pointer each time `read_models()` is called. I shall get back to the books again either way. Thanks!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I think `reset` could solve my problem. Should've thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the pointers are of different types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem**

If inside the member function you have this statement:

```
PointCloud<A>::Ptr cube_normals (new PointCloud<A>);
```

you'll create a local variable `cube_normals`, which will hide the class member with the same name.

**The solution**

If the goal is to create a new empty object every time you call `read_models()` you could opt for an assignment.

The problem is that the following does not necessarily work, depending how `Ptr` is defined:

```
cube_normals = new PointCloud<A>;  // but what do you do with the old pointer ??
```

Assuming that your smartpointer class is something like:

```
template <class T>
class PointCloud {
public: 
    using Ptr = shared_ptr<T>;
};
```

You could then opt for a simple:

```
cube_normals = PointCloud<A>::Ptr(new A);
```

This [compiles nicely](http://ideone.com/U3NYil), although it would be better to use make_shared or make_unique depending on the kind of smart pointer you're using.

My advice would be to work on `PointCloud`, to ensure a proper smartpointer interface, including resting a pointer to null, and ore create a pointer to new object.